# What is the performance difference between multiple ReactDOM.render and one ReactDOM.createPortal?

Tags: reactjs

This is one of the questions I was asked during the interview, but I didn't answer it. What do you think?

Comment: Why rely on other people's opinions when you can find out for yourself using the [profiler API](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html) and your browser's native profiler in dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

Events are not propagated to the parent in `render` while it does in `createPortal`.

From the docs on React Portals,

> This includes event bubbling. An event fired from inside a portal will
> propagate to ancestors in the containing React tree, even if those
> elements are not ancestors in the DOM tree.

Read this [Event Bubbling Through Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#event-bubbling-through-portals)

Check this Demo,

[image: Edit create-portal-vs-render]